# How do we show there are the same number of elements in each of the sets?

Tags: group-theory

If $f: G \to H$ is an isomorphism of groups then show that for any integer $k$ and $g \in G$, these sets $A = \{a \in G : a^k = g$} and $B = \{b \in H : b^k = f(g)\}$ have the same number of elements.

Comment: Hint: What conditions must the function $f$ satisfy so that $f:G\to H$ is an isomorphism?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $f(a^k)=f(a)^k$ and $f^{-1}(b^k)=(f^{-1}(b))^k$ Now can you define a bijection between $A$ and $B$ ?

Comment: I defined the function $\phi : A \to B$ by $\phi(a) = f(a^k)$, which I can show is injective: If $a_1, a_2 \in A$, then $\phi(a_1) = \phi_(a_2)$ implies $f(a_1^k) = f(a_2^k)$ implies $a_1 = a_2$ since $f$ is injective. I can't prove if $\phi$ is surjective.

Comment: @Jia: you need to also use $f^{-1}$, it is an isomorphism from $H$ to $G$.

Comment: For each $b \in B \subseteq H $ there exist $g$ such that $b^k =f(g)$. Therese exist $a \in H $ such that $ a^k = g$ then $ f(a)^k = f(g)= b^k$